# Can not set int field com.java.hibernate.practise.User.id to java.util.HashSet

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
I have hibernate @OneToMany mapping I am getting the mentioned error. Does not understand the reason. As getters and setters are public

Below are the entities

@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="USER_FIRSTNAME",nullable=false, length=50)
    private String userFirstName;

    @Column(name="USER_LASTNAME",nullable=false, length=50)
    private String userLastName;

    @Column(name="USER_MIDDLENAME",length = 30)
    private String userMiddleName;

    @Column(name="USER_AGE")
    private int userAge;

    @Column(name="USER_SEX")
    private String userSex;


    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="userAddress", targetEntity=Address.class)
    private Set<Address> address = new HashSet<Address>();

    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return userFirstName;
    }

    public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
    }

    public String getUserLastName() {
        return userLastName;
    }

    public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
    }

    public String getUserMiddleName() {
        return userMiddleName;
    }

    public void setUserMiddleName(String userMiddleName) {
        this.userMiddleName = userMiddleName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }

    public String getUserSex() {
        return userSex;
    }

    public void setUserSex(String userSex) {
        this.userSex = userSex;
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Set<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name="ADDRESS_USER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long addressUserID;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_SEC")
    private String addressSec;

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_USER_ID")
    private Set<User> userAddress = new HashSet<User>();

    public Long getAddressUserID() {
        return addressUserID;
    }

    public void setAddressUserID(Long addressUserID) {
        this.addressUserID = addressUserID;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Set<User> getUserAddress() {
        return userAddress;
    }

    public void setUserAddress(Set<User> userAddress) {
        this.userAddress = userAddress;
    }


    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getAddressSec() {
        return addressSec;
    }

    public void setAddressSec(String addressSec) {
        this.addressSec = addressSec;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}

    Part of Stack Trace are:
```

**Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.java.hibernate.practise.User.id** at...      org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62)
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.java.hibernate.practise.User.id to java.util.HashSet**...

I am generating the schema using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= cerate-drop
Please guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when we use 1..n bidirectional entity mapping, the owning side which is in general, the many side, should have only a single instance reference to the one side object (not a collection - that would be many to many), and the join column to use is the primary key from the on side class. We don't need to explicitly use the FK column in the many side like you are.

So if this is your relationship `User [1]..[N] Address`, then you should have something more like

```
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Address> addresses;
}

public class Address {
    // private Long addressUserID; // Don't need this property. We get it below
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
}
```